# Update a record's field using other records field which have matched value in others field

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with these fields:

- Open_date
- Account_No
- Account_Type
- Currency
- Close_Date
- Client_Type

All of these fields value will not have any null, except for client_type field. The client_type field will have null but the majority of the row is not null.

I'm looking for a way to update each row's client_type if it's null using the value of client_type of another row, which client_type is not null, that have matching open_date, account_type, currency and close_date.

I had try merge 2 sub-query(one search for null and other search for not null) and then update the table client_type where open_date, account_type, currency and close_date of 2 sub-query need to be match. This statement took more than 20 mins to run which I have to cancel it and I doubt it correct anyway.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you post any sample data that would match the conditions you are referring?

Comment: Merge is the efficient way for update. Other option is to create a new table using ctas by selecting from the old table with the condition you want and drop the old table and rename the new tables.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and "TOAD" is a SQL client that can connect to different database products). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Tables have rows and columns, not records or fields.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? You self join the table only where `Client_Type IS NOT NULL`. Then when `Client_Type IS NULL`, use the `Client_Type` from the self join.

```
SELECT t1.Open_date,
       t1.Account_No,
       t1.Account_Type,
       t1.Currency,
       t1.Close_Date,
       NVL(t1.Client_Type, t2.Client_Type)

  FROM t1
       LEFT JOIN t1 t2
       ON t1.Open_date = t2.Open_date
          AND t1.Account_No = t2.Account_No
          AND t1.Account_Type = t2.Account_Type
          AND t1.Currency = t2.Currency
          AND t1.Close_Date = t2.Close_Date
          AND Client_Type IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable1') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #myTable1
END;

CREATE TABLE #myTable1 (Open_date    datetime,Account_No   int,Account_Type varchar(100),Currency     varchar(100),Close_Date   datetime,Client_Type  varchar(100))

Insert INTO #myTable1(Open_date, Account_No, Account_type, Currency, close_date, client_type)
values
  ('2019-12-12', 1, 'AcctType 1', 'C1', '2019-12-12', 'ct1')
, ('2019-12-13', 2, 'AcctType 2', 'C2', '2019-12-13', 'ct2')
, ('2019-12-14', 3, 'AcctType 3', 'C3', '2019-12-14', 'ct3')
, ('2019-12-12', 4, 'AcctType 1', 'C1', '2019-12-12', null)

--select * from #myTable1

update t2
   set t2.client_type = t1.client_type
--select *
   from #myTable1 t1
   left join #myTable1 t2 
       on t1.Open_date = t2.Open_date 
           and t1.Account_Type = t2.Account_Type 
           and t1.Currency = t2.Currency 
           and t1.Close_Date = t2.Close_Date 

   where 
      t2.Client_Type is null 
      and 
      t1.Client_Type is not null
 select * from #myTable1
```